# Seleniumを使ったスクレイピングで、最後のページが終了したらbreakさせたい。

Tags: python, python3, selenium, selenium-webdriver

## 目的

↓のURLに表示される全ての一覧ページの求人詳細URLを取得したい。
（ただし、求人の数は変動する。今回は291件）
https://next.rikunabi.com/eigyo/lst_jb0101020000/

## 期待する結果

```
[https://next.rikunabi.com/company/cmi2566412298/nx1_rq0016317040/?fr=cp_s00700&list_disp_no=1&leadtc=n_ichiran_cst_n5_ttl, 
https://next.rikunabi.com/company/cmi1886534023/nx1_rq0016914472/?fr=cp_s00700&list_disp_no=2&leadtc=n_ichiran_cst_n5_ttl,
https://next.rikunabi.com/company/cmi3761586187/nx1_rq0019382037/?fr=cp_s00700&list_disp_no=3&leadtc=n_ichiran_cst_n5_ttl,
....n件分]
```

## 書いたコード

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

#サイトのベースとなるURLを変数に入れる。
rikunabi_base_url = 'https://next.rikunabi.com/eigyo/lst_jb0101020000/crn'
page_count = 1
offer_employment_url_li = []


while True:
    rikunabi_employment_list_url = rikunabi_base_url + str(page_count) + '.html'
    driver.get(rikunabi_employment_list_url)

    #50件分の求人詳細URLを取得し、リストに入れる。
    offer_employment_url_li_object = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.rnn-textLl a')
    for offer_employment_url in offer_employment_url_li_object:
        offer_employment_url = offer_employment_url.get_attribute('href')
        offer_employment_url_li.append(offer_employment_url)

    #『次へ』ボタンから次のページURLを取得、なければ終了
    next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.rnn-wrapper.js-rnnWrapper > div > div > div.rnn-row.rnn-row--gutter-xm > div.rnn-col-9.rnn-group.rnn-group--xm.js-resultSearch.rnn-col-offset-3 > div.rnn-group.rnn-group--xm > div.rnn-group.rnn-group--xs > div > ul > li.rnn-pagination__next > a')
    next_page_url = next_page.get_attribute('href')
    if next_page_url:
        page_count += 50
        continue
    break

print(offer_employment_url_li)
```

## 結果

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-0892f82cfce7> in <module>
     27 
     28     #『次へ』ボタンから次のページURLを取得、なければ終了
---> 29     next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.rnn-wrapper.js-rnnWrapper > div > div > div.rnn-row.rnn-row--gutter-xm > div.rnn-col-9.rnn-group.rnn-group--xm.js-resultSearch.rnn-col-offset-3 > div.rnn-group.rnn-group--xm > div.rnn-group.rnn-group--xs > div > ul > li.rnn-pagination__next > a')
     30     next_page_url = next_page.get_attribute('href')
     31     if next_page_url:

〜〜略〜〜

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body > div.rnn-wrapper.js-rnnWrapper > div > div > div.rnn-row.rnn-row--gutter-xm > div.rnn-col-9.rnn-group.rnn-group--xm.js-resultSearch.rnn-col-offset-3 > div.rnn-group.rnn-group--xm > div.rnn-group.rnn-group--xs > div > ul > li.rnn-pagination__next > a"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=84.0.4147.105)
```

計6ページ291件のURL取得後、7ページ目のURL取得の時にbreakさせたいのですが、
セレクターが取得できないエラーが出てしまいます。
全URL取得後にbreakできれば方法は問いません。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「セレクターが取得できないエラーが出てしまいます。」ということなので、それを基に`try: except:`で判定して終了させれば良いでしょう。
以下のような感じで出来ると思います。

```
#『次へ』ボタンから次のページURLを取得、なければ終了
try:
    next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(...)  ## 長いので省略
    next_page_url = next_page.get_attribute('href')
except:
    next_page_url = ''

if next_page_url:
```

Comment: おお、うまくいきました。@kunif さんありがとうございます！